# $scope.headings data value undefined outside of $http.get

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

**Goal:** Populate a table that has dynamic table headings (retrieved via GET). As such, the values (retrieved via another GET) to be used to populate the table have a header_id that can connect the two:

i.e.

> headers = [{name:header1, id:1}, {name:header2, id2}] 
>   list_entries = [{value:'pop', header_id:1},{value:'bop', header_id:3}]

I can't directly use ng-repeat on list_entries to populate the table since I must respect the fact that some table cells will be empty (no value matched to a header).

I want to access $scope.headings so that I can iterate through it and then use logic to match a value to it (compare header_id).

This may seem like a dumb question to others, but I really have tried looking all over for a good approach. I'd really appreciate just being pointed in the right direction with respect to this.

```
<script>
    var list = angular.module('listApps', []);

    list.config(function($httpProvider) {
             ... set defaults ...
    });

    list.controller('ListCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout){

        var table_headings = xxxxxx; //root + ending

        /* Pull Table Headings*/    
        $http.get(table_headings.toString()).success(function(data,status){
            $scope.headings = data.response.fields_names;
            $scope.status = status;
            console.log(data.response.fields_names);
        }).error(function(result,status){
            $scope.data = result.data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = status;
        });

        // match table headings to the respective values in order to populate table correctly
        $scope.mapping = [];

        // At this point, not even focusing on the function; just need to access $scope.headings
        angular.forEach($scope.headings, function(value, key){
            this.push(key+':'+value);
        }, $scope.mapping);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: do the mapping within success callback

Comment: Since the values are gotten via a GET request, would it be okay to nest the GET for values within the GET for headings?

Comment: there are ways to do both requests at same time and use angular's `$q` promise library to wait for both to complete before running code. But I'm guessing AJAX is new to you, so yes you could do second request after first that way. Just takes a little bit longer

Comment: Thanks for the tip about $q ! Good guessing - I am new, but I found it useful to look into for learning purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do it like this too (the idea is to call the properties of your data using the string notation with the ng-repeat directive, ie: item['property'] instead of item.property):

**Result** [[Link to the image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAshX.png)
[image]

As you can see, if the field doesn't exist for an object, it is blank.

**Template**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-ng-repeat="head in headings">{{head.title}}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in data">
        <td data-ng-repeat="head in headings">{{item.id}} {{item[head.id]}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Controller**

```
function ListCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('api/headings.json').then(function(result) {
        $scope.headings = result.data;    
    });
    $http.get('api/data.json').then(function(result) {
        $scope.data = result.data;
    });
}
```

**Data fields corresponding to the template**

```
[
    {"id": "H1", "title": "Heading 1"},
    {"id": "H3", "title": "Heading 3"},
    {"id": "H5", "title": "Heading 5"}
] /* headings.json */
```

and

```
[
    {"id": "D1", "H2": "Data H2D1", "H3": "Data H3D1", "H4": "Data H4D1", "H5": "Data H5D1"},
    {"id": "D2", "H1": "Data H1D2", "H2": "Data H2D2", "H3": "Data H3D2", "H4": "Data H4D2"},
    {"id": "D3", "H1": "Data H1D3", "H2": "Data H2D3", "H3": "Data H3D3", "H4": "Data H4D3", "H5": "Data H5D3"},
    {"id": "D4", "H1": "Data H1D4", "H2": "Data H2D4", "H4": "Data H4D4", "H5": "Data H5D4"},
    {"id": "D5", "H1": "Data H1D5", "H2": "Data H2D5", "H3": "Data H3D5", "H4": "Data H4D5", "H5": "Data H5D5"}
] /* data.json with missing fields*/
```

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive example!